# How do i concat the Int or Long to a List in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have this:

```
val vertexIdListPartitions: TrieMap[Long, List[Long]]
```

I need to have something like this:

`vertexIdListPartitions(0)` -> `List[2,3,4,5,etc..]`

But when I add numbers in the list in this way:

```
for(c<- 0 to 10)
   vertexIdListPartitions.update(0,List(c))
```

The result is `List[10]`

How can I concat them?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you don't need a `for` loop:

```
import scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap

val vertexIdListPartitions = TrieMap[Long, List[Long]]()

vertexIdListPartitions.update(0, (0L to 10L).toList)
// res1: scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Long,List[Long]] = 
// TrieMap(0 -> List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

[UPDATE]

Below is a method for adding or concatenating a key-value `tuple` to the `TrieMap` accordingly:

```
def concatTM( tm: TrieMap[Long, List[Long]], kv: Tuple2[Long, List[Long]] ) =
  tm += ( tm.get(kv._1) match {
    case Some(l: List[Long]) => (kv._1 -> (l ::: kv._2))
    case None => kv
  } )

concatTM( vertexIdListPartitions, (1L, List(1L, 2L, 3L)) )
// res2: scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Long,List[Long]] =
// TrieMap(0 -> List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 1 -> List(1, 2, 3))

concatTM( vertexIdListPartitions, (0L, List(11L, 12L)) )
// res61: scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Long,List[Long]] = 
// TrieMap(0 -> List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 1 -> List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Actually I meant random numbers not 0 to 10

Comment: Your original question indicates nothing about randomness.  Anyway, please see my updated answer whether that addresses your need.